# Java: EDT, SwingUtilities & GUILock

Tags: java, user-interface, listener, event-dispatch-thread

I am using an actionListener to trigger an sequence of events and ultimatley this code is called:

```
public class ScriptManager {

public static Class currentScript;
private Object ScriptInstance;
public int State = 0;
// 0 = Not Running
// 1 = Running
// 2 = Paused

private Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            currentScript.getMethod("run").invoke(ScriptInstance);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

public void runScript() {
    try {
        ScriptInstance = currentScript.newInstance();
        new Thread(thread).start();
        State = 1;
        MainFrame.onPause();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   

public void pauseScript() {
    try {
        thread.wait();
        System.out.println("paused");
        State = 2;
        MainFrame.onPause();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void resumeScript() {
    try {
        thread.notify();
        System.out.println("resumed");
        State = 1;
        MainFrame.onResume();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void stopScript() {
    try {
        thread.interrupt();
        thread.join();
        System.out.println("stopped");
        State = 0;
        MainFrame.onStop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
}
```

The runnable is created and ran, however, the problem occurs when I try to use the any of the other methods, they lock my UI. (I'm assuming this is because im running this on the EDT) Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you use `wait` and `notify`. They need to be executed on the thread that you are trying to pause and resume. Which means you need to send a message to the other thread somehow. There are various ways to do this, but the other thread needs to be listening for this message, or at least check for it occassionally.

Comment: I am trying to pause the Runnable I created in the class. the one called 'thread'.

Comment: Yes, I realise that. But you say you're running this on the EDT, which as I said in my answer, is not the correct way to use wait and notify.

Comment: It is being called via actionlistener which runs on the EDT, also I am using SwingUtilities and a runnable to set LAF with UIManager. What I want however, is for the runnable to pause.

Comment: Yes... so as I already said, you need to send a message to the other thread. E.g. you could use a queue. The challenge is going to be making the other thread listen to the message. Since I have no idea what the other thread is doing, I can't really suggest anything without further information.

Comment: What if I created a middle class between this and what the thread is supposed to do, and called the methods that way?

Comment: It doesn't matter what class you put the code in, it's still going to be ran in the wrong thread. Calling a method in a different class still means you're on the same thread.

Comment: No wait, your right... Well thanks for your answers I guess ill just have to try something else